# Разработка таблицы в формате Single PAge Application

Tags: spa

Подскажите пожалуйста как мне решить данную задачу!Таблица содержит 4 столбца.
1 дата 2 название 3 количество 4 расстояние
База данных MySql
Таблица должна иметь сортировку по всем полям кроме даты. Фильтрация должна быть  виде двух выпадающих списков и текстового поля. а)Выбор колонки по которой будет фильтрация б)Выбор условия(равно,содержит,больше,меньше) с)Поле для ввода значения для фильтрации.
Таблица должна содержать пагинацию.Вся таблица должна работать без без перезагрузки страцницы.

Comment: Что конкретно подсказать?

Comment: как ее сделать не понимаю что конретно хотят

Comment: Я так понимаю на node js?

Comment: Или на чем-то другом?